# Using actual images for emoticons in HTML

Tags: html, unicode, emoticons

I know that we can use [Unicode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12764767/4283301) to represent emoticons as characters in browsers that support that part of the Unicode range (not all of them).

However, I want to use the (standard emoticons, not a green knock-off) package as images, rather than as Unicode characters, to ensure that anyone on any browser can see them, as they will occupy a functionally important part of a site I am working on.

Does anyone know where I could find the images (as PNG/JPG/GIF) rendered/represented by the Unicode?

Comment: Not clear what you're looking for. Fonts that support the full unicode char set will display _characters_, not _images_.

Comment: @Mogsdad Exactly - I want the images, not the characters, so that I can display them. I've found what I was looking for and posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is what I was looking for, hope this helps someone else:

http://www.emoji-cheat-sheet.com/

This site has all the emoticons as PNG files that can be downloaded and then displayed on a website without compatability issues.